# Variable with value 0 equal string results in true

Tags: php

I have acrossed some really weird behaviour in PHP statment when having example below:

Logically it shouldn't return 1 in this context. Why this is happening ? Just was wondering.

```
$test = 0;
var_dump($test); // gives int 0
$test = ($test == 'test') ? 1 : 0;
var_dump($test); //gives int 1
```

Comment: `===` operator means identical so also the type. you should use that, == just means equal `'test'` would be 0 in that case

Comment: Do you want to know why two variables of different types can be equal to one another, or why `'test'` evaluates to `0` in this context?

Comment: @TomFenech  why 'test' evaluates to 0 in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). `'test'` is equal to `0` because `(int)'test'` actually is `0`. Thus, your condition is true and `1` is the result.

In your particular case you may want to know how PHP [converts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) strings to numbers.

Comment: +1. When one operand of comparison is number, other is converted to number too (Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). In the OP's example 1st operand is number `0` and the 2nd (`'test'` string) is converted to `0`. So the condition is evaluated as `0 == 0`

Answer (score 2):

Just try with `===` to compare also type of values:

```
$test = ($test === 'test') ? 1 : 0;
```